# Google Maps Javascript: load file:/// URLs

Tags: google-maps

Based on Google's recent [announcement](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/standard-plan-2016-update) I need a way to load the Google Maps Javscript API from my mobile hybrid/Cordova app. I could whitelist `file:///` URLs from my console, but I'd rather not because that means anyone who could learn my client ID could then use it in their own app and I'd have no way to protect myself from that.

Apparently Google now supports some kind of API key, but only for Premium accounts created since January of this year, which mine is not. 
Is there some other way to allow my mobile app to access the Google Maps Javascript API without opening up such a risk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are a **Standard Plan** user: you need to load the Maps Javascript API with a key. Per the [current limitation on API keys](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9996) and file:// URLs, you will have to open up the key. You can star this bug to be alerted of updates.

If you are a **Premium Plan** user, you also have the option to use a client ID, which can be more tightly secured. You can [file a support case](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/support#google-for-work-support-portal) to request that your client ID authorizes only the file:// URL(s) that you are using.

**UPDATE**

Restrictions for file protocol were introduced in Google Maps JavaScript API. You can find information in the official documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key-restrictions

> file:// referers need a special representation to be added to the Key restriction. The "file:/" part should be replaced with "__file_url__" before being added to the Key restriction. For example, "file:///path/to/" should be formatted as "__file_url__//path/to/*". After enabling file:// referers, it is recommended you regularly check your usage, to make sure it matches your expectations.